# On an inequality involving the Euler's totient function and the Lambert $W$ function

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, analytic-number-theory, totient-function, lambert-w

I wondered if it is possible to refute or prove this conjecture that I've considered.

**Conjecture.** *There exists a positive real number* $x_0$ such that 
$$\frac{x}{\varphi(x)}<\frac{\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}{\zeta(6)}\cdot W_0\left(\exp\left(-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{\log x}\right)\right)\right)\tag{1}$$
*holds for all integer* $x>x_0$, *where* $\varphi(x)$ *denotes the Euler's totient function,* $W_k(x)$ *the analytic continuation, the different branchs, of the Lambert* $W$ *function and* $\zeta(s)$ *the Riemann's zeta function.*

The Wikipedia has an article for [*Lambert* $W$ *function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) and other for [*Euler's totient function.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)

> **Question.** Is it possible to prove previous conjecture? For what choice of $x_0$? **Many thanks.**

I doubt that the known inequalities that involve the Euler's totient function are enough to prove it.

I tried to create it with the purpose that the *RHS* of the inequality $(1)$ will be approximately a multiple of $\log\log x$, but I have no a good motivation for the choice of the value of the constant $\frac{\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}{\zeta(6)}$ in the *RHS*.

Comment: Could you tell what is your motivation for such an elaborate inequality ?

Comment: Are you aware of Nicolas' criterion for the Riemann Hypothesis (RH)? If the RH is true, then for all $k\ge 1$: $N_k/\varphi(N_k)>e^{\gamma}\log\log N_k$ where $N_k$ is a primorial number ($N_k$ is the product of the first $k$ primes).

Comment: Many thanks @JeanMarie I've no a good motivation to state this kind of inequalities that involve the number theoretic functions and the Lambert $W$ function. On the other hand are proliferating, in my view, papers about the asymptotic of primes and its relationship with the Lambert $W$ function. I'm trying to evoke statements inspired from in **Lemme 2.2** by Jean-Louis Nicolas, *Quelques inégalités effectives entre des fonctions arithmétiques usuelles*, Funct. Approx. Comment. Math. Volume 39, Number 2 (2008) that is available from Project Euclid (it is the Lemme 2 from the preprint on arXiv)

Comment: Many thanks @StevenClark , please read previous comment to know the mentioned  bilbiography. I don't know if my conjecture is consistent with Riemann hypothesis, I am evoking to state conjectures inspired from **Lemme 2.2** by the paper of Jean-Louis Nicolas. For example my belief is that $$\frac{n}{\varphi(n)}<\frac{1}{\zeta(4)}W_0(\varphi(n))$$ for all integer $n>3570=2\cdot 3\cdot5\cdot 7\cdot 17$, where again the constant $1/\zeta(4)$ did not arise from calculations. In fact I don't know if this conjecture is just a special case of **Lemme 2.2** from the paper of Jean-Louis Nicolas.